# Regex to breakdown string into Firstname(s), Surname and Location

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I have some records of people that I want to breakdown the information for in the following way:

- Anything within brackets can be considered a location
- Surname will be
  the last word - excluding the location above
- Firstname(s) will be
  everything before the Surname

Possibly a few incorrect assumptions in here, i.e. single word surnames. I'm looking to use regex to do the bulk and am keep to get ideas around this. The implementation of the regular expression will be in PHP.

Here are some example records:

```
Sam Leicester
Sam Christopher Leicester
Sam Leicester (London)
Sam Christopher Leicester (France)
```

So far I've produced this http://regexr.com/39cbk which parses the names into an array (easy to use last element as surname, and rest joined as firstname(s)) With a recond group for the location. Although I don't seem to have any joy implementing this with [preg_match()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) yet.

Comment: For those of you common to regex I'm hoping this is a walk in the park, but hopefully will help me and others learn, and possibly raise other ideas and considerations.

Comment: as the last name and location are interchangeable it is impossible to logically determine whether its a last name or location, unless you have a big list of all possible locations...

Comment: or is leicester a last name?!

Comment: Yes, without thinking about the confusion it my cause and using myself as an example, Leicester is my surname :-) Locations are always provided in brackets.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use named groups to make life easier and use such regexp:

```
/^(?P<name>\w+ (?:\w+ )*?)(?P<secondName>\w+(?: |$))?(?:\((?P<location>\w+)\))?$/m
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/iC0zO8/3)

Or without named groups:

```
/^(\w+ (?:\w+ )*?)(\w+(?: |$))?(?:\((\w+)\))?$/m
```

This regexp works well also when user specified only name and location.

Answer (score 5):

You can use this regex:

```
/^(.*)\s(\w+)(?:\s\((\w+)\))?$/
```

[View a regex demo.](http://regex101.com/r/fV2wD3/3)

The first capturing group `(.*)` attempts to match anything. This allows the engine to backtrack. If locations in brackets are absent, we simply match the surname (`(\w+)`) and escape, otherwise we will match both the surname `(\w+)` and the location in two Capturing groups.